# Run several python scripts with parallel

Tags: bash, gpu, xargs, gnu-parallel

I have `run_command_list.txt` which contrain one command per line:

```
time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_1 --batch_size 1 > bs_1.log
time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_2 --batch_size 2 > bs_2.log
time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_4 --batch_size 4 > bs_4.log
...
```

I want to run not more that 2 jobs in parallel and I want to set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 or CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 depending on which GPU is available at the moment, how can I do this using `parallel` or `xargs`?

i.e. something like `cat run_command_list.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 2`

Comment: How do you determine which GPU is available?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449224/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-the-xargs-parallel-processor

Answer (score 1):

```
seq 1000 |
  parallel -j2 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='{=1 $_=slot()-1 =}' time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_{} --batch_size {} '>' bs_{}.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
function GET_AVAILABLE_DEVICE() {
    [[ SOMETHING_HERE == SOMETHING ]] && echo 0 || echo 1
}

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$( GET_AVAILABLE_DEVICE ) time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_1 --batch_size 1 > bs_1.log &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$( GET_AVAILABLE_DEVICE ) time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_2 --batch_size 2 > bs_2.log &
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=$( GET_AVAILABLE_DEVICE ) time python3 train.py --dataroot ./datasets/maps --name maps_pix2pix --model pix2pix --direction AtoB --checkpoints_dir maps_pix2pix_a_to_b_bs_4 --batch_size 4 > bs_4.log &
wait
```

You need to replace *SOMETHING_HERE== SOMETHING* with whatever command will give you your available device.